# Stop form submission when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form where user enter a cnic number if this number is less than 15 then alert a msg and stop the form submission but issue is that form submission cannot stop when the `cnic` number is less than 15.

```
<script>
    function validateform()
    {

        var cnic1 = document.getElementById("cnic1").value;
        if (cnic1.length < 15)
        {
            window.alert("Invalid CNIC");
            cnic1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form class="col s12" action="tabs.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="applyform">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s1"></div>
        <div class="input-field col s4"><label>CNIC No. </label>
            <font style="color: #ff0000">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="cnic1" name="cnic1" type="text" value="<?php echo $RowAcc['cnic'];?>" maxlength="15" placeholder="CNIC #" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there issue in php submission code write on `tabs.php` page that's why form still submitting process?

Comment: You can use e.stopPropagation(); https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to return `false` to stop the form from being submitted. You need to use the event's `preventDefault()` method, and submit the form using JS if the data is valid. Like this:

```
function validateform(e) { // take the event as parameter
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

    var cnic1 = document.getElementById("cnic1");

    if (cnic1.value.length < 15) {
        window.alert("Invalid CNIC");
        cnic1.focus();
    } else {
        form.submit();
    }
}

var form = document.getElementsByName('applyform')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', validateform);
```

I also added the listener using JS just so you can be sure the event parameter is passed to your validation function. Remove the `onsubmit="..."` from your form.

Comment: When selecting only a single element, I'd prefer `querySelector`, rather than use a method that returns a collection and proceed to select the first element in the collection

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's the same, and using querySelector is slower and more complicated to write if matching a name.

Comment: Form is still submitting if CNIC number is less than 15

Comment: @AhilKhan did you use JS to add the event listener and removed the onsubmit="..." from the HTML?

Comment: @AhilKhan Well, justa fter the function declaration. Amd be sure your `<script>` is after the form too.

Comment: `function validateform(e)
  {
   document.getElementsByName('applyform')[0].addEventListener('submit', validateform);
   var cnic1 = document.getElementById("cnic1").value;
   if (cnic1.length < 15)
   {
       window.alert("Invalid CNIC");
       cnic1.focus();
       e.preventDefault();
   }
  }`

Comment: I changed it but still form is submit

Comment: Not inside the function! Outside the function. Look at my answer I edited the code.

Comment: form still submitting

Comment: Now its working but still problem is that if **CNIC number** is 15 then form is submit but dont send the value of this **CNIC number** into database

Comment: Well that's another problem. Make your question clearer.

Comment: but little bit my problem is solved form stop submitting

Answer (score 0):

Call the js function from onchange = "" event, or use any button and call click event. Your js function will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
return false;
```

or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [peventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method