# signup button doesn't redirect to my login page, how can i fix this? i'm a beginner at javascript coding

Tags: javascript, html

i want to know what's the problem and how i can rewrite the code to make it work! please and thank you in advance!

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="signupForm">
        
        <h2>Welcome! Sign up here.</h2>

        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="User Name">
        <p id="outputName"></p>
        
        <input type="date" id="birthday" placeholder="Birth date">
        
        <input type="address" id="address" placeholder="Address">
        <p id="outputAddress"></p>
        
        <input type="number" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <p id="outputPhoneNumber"></p>
        
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <p id="outputEmail"></p>
        
        <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
        <p id="outputPass"></p>
        
        <input type="password" id="confirm-pass" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
        <p id="outputConfPass"></p>
        
        <button id="submit" onclick="validateForm()">Register</button>

    </form>
    <script src="signup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my javascript code

```
function validateForm() {
  // Username validation
  let username = document.getElementById("name1");
  if (username == '') {
    document.getElementById("outputName").innerHTML = "The username field must be filled out!";
  }

  // Address validation
  let address = document.getElementById("address1");
  if (address == '') {
    document.getElementById("outputAddress").innerHTML = "The address field must be filled out!";
  }

  // Phone number validation
  let phoneNum = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
  let numFormat = /^\d{11}$/;
  if (phoneNum.value.match(numFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("outputPhoneNumber").innerHTML = "Number confirmation successful!"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("outputPhoneNumber").innerHTML = "Invalid phone number format!";
  }

  // Email validation
  let email = document.getElementById("email");
  let emailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

  if (email.value.match(emailFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("outputEmail").innerHTML = "Valid email address!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("outputEmail").innerHTML = "Invalid email address!";
  
  }

  // Password validation
  let password = document.getElementById("pass");
  let confirmPass = document.getElementById("confirm-pass");
  let passFormat = /^(?!.*\s).{8}$/;

  if (password.value.match(passFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("outputPass").innerHTML = "Password must be atleast 8 characters with one special character";
    
  } else if (password != confirmPass) {
    document.getElementById("outputPass").innerHTML = "Your password does not match!";
   
  } else { //Submit form
    document.getElementById("signupForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
    
      window.location.href = "/login.html";
    });
  }
}
```

i tried searching the internet for solutions but i cant seem to find anything, i've tried for 2 days now and i still cant do anything to fix it.

Comment: You don't stop the normal submission of your form. This is the first thing you need to do in `validateForm()`. See: [Event: preventDefault() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). See for instance [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314836/stop-form-submission-when-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Three things:
One, you use location.href, not window.location.href, 
Two, you'll need to stop the default action by adding 'type="button"' to the button,
Three, some of the field validation logic don't work, 'password, confirm-password'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [form action](https://www.w3schools.am/tags/att_form_action.html#gsc.tab=0) instead of `window.location.href` to navigate to different page.

```
<form action="/login.html">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="User Name">
    <p id="outputName"></p>
        
    <input type="date" id="birthday" placeholder="Birth date">
        
    <input type="address" id="address" placeholder="Address">
    <p id="outputAddress"></p>
        
    <input type="number" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <p id="outputPhoneNumber"></p>
        
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <p id="outputEmail"></p>
        
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <p id="outputPass"></p>
        
    <input type="password" id="confirm-pass" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
    <p id="outputConfPass"></p>
        
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Register</button>
</form>
```

and your JavaScript will be:

```
if (password.value.match(passFormat)) {
    document.getElementById("outputPass").innerHTML = "Password must be atleast 8 characters with one special character";
    
} else if (password != confirmPass) {
    document.getElementById("outputPass").innerHTML = "Your password does not match!";
   
} else { //Submit form
    alert("Welcome User!");
}
```

Note that I have removed the `"submit"` event listener as there is already `onClick` which fires the function when you clicked on the button.

**UPDATE**: I have recreated the code from scratch, so I apologize for some modifications I made with your code.

If the above does not work for some reason, here is another approach which utilizes both form action and `window.location.href`:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.html" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
        <h1>Welcome! Sign up here.</h1>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <p id="username-label"></p>

        <input type="date" id="birthday"/>
        
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address"/>
        <p id="address-label"></p>

        <input type="number" id="phone-number" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
        <p id="phone-number-label"></p>

        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <p id="email-label"></p>

        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <p id="password-label"></p>

        <input type="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
        <p id="confirm-password-label"></p>

        <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

*script.js*

```
function validateForm(event) {
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const usernameLabel = document.getElementById("username-label");
    const address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    const addressLabel = document.getElementById("address-label");
    const phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone-number").value;
    const phoneNumberLabel = document.getElementById("phone-number-label");
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const emailLabel = document.getElementById("email-label");
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const passwordLabel = document.getElementById("password-label");
    const confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirm-password").value;
    const confirmPasswordLabel = document.getElementById("confirm-password-label");

    if (!username || !address || !phoneNumber || !email || !password || !confirmPassword) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!username) {
        usernameLabel.innerHTML = "The username field must be filled out!";
    }
    if (!address) {
        addressLabel.innerHTML = "The address field must be filled out!";
    }

    //Phone Number Validation
    const phoneNumberFormat = "/^\d{11}$/";

    if (phoneNumber.match(phoneNumberFormat)) {
        phoneNumberLabel.innerHTML = "Number confirmation successful!";
    } else {
        phoneNumberLabel.innerHTML = "Invalid phone number format!";
    }

    // Email validation
    const emailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

    if (email.match(emailFormat)) {
    emailLabel.innerHTML = "Valid email address!";
    } else {
    emailLabel.innerHTML = "Invalid email address!";
    }

    // Password validation
    const passwordFormat = /^(?!.*\s).{8}$/;

    if (password.match(passwordFormat)) {
       passwordLabel.innerHTML = "Password must be atleast 8 characters with one special character";
        
    } else if (password != confirmPassword) {
        passwordLabel.innerHTML = "Your password does not match!";
        confirmPasswordLabel.innerHTML = "Your password does not match!";
    } else { 
        alert("Login successful!");
        window.location.href = "/login.html";
    }
}
```

The above code makes the form go to `login.html` by default using the form action disregarding the changes made by the validateForm function, but we prevented it to happen using `event.preventDefault()`. Then at the last condition, if the password matches, the user will then be navigated to `login.html`.

Note: I have changed the input type of address field to `text` as there is no input of type address. See [input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) for the list of types.

Comment: I tried the code but it does not work on my end

Comment: Do you mind telling the specifics of "it does not work"? What is the expected output and what is the actual outcome? Note that you should only place the provided code to a specific part of your code and not the entire file.

Comment: yes i did exactly that and it remained in the sign up page. my goal is that when i click the button, it validates the form and if every value returns true, it should redirect to my login page.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You might want to look at it to see if it works and if it makes sense.